# UICollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths slows down with large quantity of UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that can have up to 1000 `UICollectionViewCells` loaded. When I call `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` depending on the number of  cell's in the collection view, it can take a long time to update the UI. I have pinpointed that the problem (in my code anyway) lies between `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` and `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` using this code:

```
- (void)updateIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSLog(@"starting reload of row %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
    NSLog(@"finished reload of row %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"begin creating cell at row %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    // Customise the cell
    NSLog(@"end creating cell at row %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    return cell;
}
```

(Note that I only want to update 1 indexPath at a time)

When the collection view has 5 cell's it takes just 40ms:

```
2014-03-14 13:07:10.949 Fotobox[2903:60b] starting reload of row 0
2014-03-14 13:07:10.954 Fotobox[2903:60b] begin creating cell at row 0
2014-03-14 13:07:10.974 Fotobox[2903:60b] end creating cell at row 0
2014-03-14 13:07:10.989 Fotobox[2903:60b] finished reload of row 0
```

But with 316 cell's it takes 3.4s:

```
2014-03-14 13:08:48.222 Fotobox[2903:60b] starting reload of row 0
2014-03-14 13:08:51.679 Fotobox[2903:60b] begin creating cell at row 0
2014-03-14 13:08:51.708 Fotobox[2903:60b] end creating cell at row 0
2014-03-14 13:08:51.725 Fotobox[2903:60b] finished reload of row 0
```

**Is there something I can do about this to speed it up?**
I'm guessing this is internal to UICollectionView, but I would love to be proven wrong.

Thanks.